# Junit and jenkins org.junit.contrib.java.lang.system.internal.CheckExitCalled: Tried to exit with status 0

Tags: java, jenkins, junit, system-rules

I try to run junit tests in parallel. But while my test has to finish they dont't.
My jenkins running and seems like not gonna end.

```
The error is:
org.junit.contrib.java.lang.system.internal.CheckExitCalled: Tried to exit with status 0.
    at org.junit.contrib.java.lang.system.internal.NoExitSecurityManager.checkExit(NoExitSecurityManager.java:24)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exit(Runtime.java:107)
    at java.lang.System.exit(System.java:962)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.exit(ForkedBooter.java:144)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:127)
Exception in thread "main" org.junit.contrib.java.lang.system.internal.CheckExitCalled: Tried to exit with status 1.
    at org.junit.contrib.java.lang.system.internal.NoExitSecurityManager.checkExit(NoExitSecurityManager.java:24)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exit(Runtime.java:107)
    at java.lang.System.exit(System.java:962)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.exit(ForkedBooter.java:144)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:135)
Exception in thread "Thread-5" Exception in thread "Thread-6" org.junit.contrib.java.lang.system.internal.CheckExitCalled: Tried to exit with status 1.
    at org.junit.contrib.java.lang.system.internal.NoExitSecurityManager.checkExit(NoExitSecurityManager.java:24)
    at java.lang.Runtime.halt(Runtime.java:273)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter$1.run(ForkedBooter.java:176)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
org.junit.contrib.java.lang.system.internal.CheckExitCalled: Tried to exit with status 0.
    at org.junit.contrib.java.lang.system.internal.NoExitSecurityManager.checkExit(NoExitSecurityManager.java:24)
    at java.lang.Runtime.halt(Runtime.java:273)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter$1.run(ForkedBooter.java:176)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

In my class I have:

```
@Rule
public final ExpectedSystemExit expectedSystemExit = ExpectedSystemExit.none();
```

And

```
 if(carInsuranceSteps.isCheackReservationAddressNotFoundError()) {
            Thucydides.takeScreenshot();
            expectedSystemExit.expectSystemExitWithStatus(0);
            System.exit(0);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is thrown by [System Rules](http://stefanbirkner.github.io/system-rules). It must replace the SecurityManager in order to test `System.exit()` and afterwards restores the original SecurityManager. This means that you cannot run multiple tests with System Rules in parallel in the same JVM.

Comment: The problem is that you cannot run the tests in parallel because of the testing library that you're using (`ExpectedSystemExit` is part of System Rules.)

Comment: Can you please suggest what can I do?

Comment: You could start each test in a separate JVM. See the ´forkCount´ option of Maven's Surefire plugin: https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html

Comment: Thank you Sir I did and this work for me. Thank you for help one more time.

Comment: If I use ClassRule instead of Rule for ExpectedSystemExit I get the same exception. I suppose it shouldn't static as well

Comment: @SergiiGetman Why do you think that using a ClassRule instead of a Rule will help?

Comment: @StefanBirkner I had the same exception as mentioned in question. I followed you explanation and realized that I used ClassRule. When I change it to Rule it works. So ClassRule -> Rule works to me